# Customizing SAML JIT Handler

Tags: single-sign-on, custom, code, saml, jit-handler

The Requirement is to enable SSO for all users and if the user is a new user then create an account for the user and seamlessly redirect the user to the community page from the login page.

Now I already have a script that takes care of the user creation. So I am trying to override the createUser method of the SAML JIT Handler to call my custom method. Now the createUser method returns User object but my custom method returns a boolean as it creates the user account internally.( Refer to the code below):

```
global class CustomUserCreationHandler implements Auth.SamlJitHandler {
    private class JitException extends Exception{}

    global User createUser(Id samlSsoProviderId, Id communityId, Id portalId,
        String federationIdentifier, Map<String, String> attributes, String assertion) {

        String fID= attributes.get(User.FederationIdentifier);
        String email = attributes.get(User.Email);
        Boolean flag;
        flag = CommunitySetupNewUser.createCommunityUser(fID,email);
        return null;
    }

    global void updateUser(Id userId, Id samlSsoProviderId, Id communityId, Id portalId,
        String federationIdentifier, Map<String, String> attributes, String assertion) {
       // User u = [SELECT Id, FirstName, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id=:userId];
      //  handleJit(false, u, samlSsoProviderId, communityId, portalId,
      //      federationIdentifier, attributes, assertion);
     // Boolean flag;
     // String ccoId = User.FederationIdentifier;
     // String email = null;
     // flag = PortalSetupNewUser.createPortalUser(ccoId,email);
    }
}
```

My question is , if I return a null value for the User object in createUser method, will SDFC internally redirect to the community page or will it throw some error.

Comment: why doesn't `CommunitySetupNewUser.createCommunityUser(fID,email);` return a User?

Comment: CommunitySetupNewUser.createCommunityUser(fID,email) creates the user. I tried changing the code and returning a user. Presently CommunitySetupNewUser.createCommunityUser(fID,email) populated the user object and returns it to createUser but the code is not working. Instead of logging into the community URL the application switches between the login url and community url indefinitely.